# Sophos Intelix File Hash Lookup for unknown file hash always returns reputation score 30

Tags: sophoslabs-intelix

A sophos intelix file hash lookup for an unknown file hash returns a reputation score of 30, although the file hash is not yet known by Sophos. When we then upload the file for static file analysis, we get as well a score of 30. Is this intended? I would rather prefer that the file hash lookup result indicates an error (file unknown). Are we expected to submit all files for static analysis, where the file hash lookup returns a score of 30?

```
function GetFileHash($FilePath) {
    $Hash = certutil -hashfile $FilePath SHA256
    
    return $Hash[1]
}

function LookupFileHash($Hash, $AccessToken) {
    $Headers = @{ "Authorization" = $AccessToken }
    $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Method Get -Uri "https://de.api.labs.sophos.com/lookup/files/v1/$Hash"
    $Result = $Response | ConvertTo-Json

    return $Result
}

Within foreach loop:

$Hash = GetFileHash $_.FullName
$LookupResult = LookupFileHash $Hash $AccessToken
```

Use case: Checking own compiled files and 3rd party files during build process.

- When building .NET Windows desktop applications, check own and 3rd party files from nugets (especially nuget.org), 3rd party runtimes and SDKs before generating the installer msi file.
- When building Electron based applications, check all included 3rd party binaries before generating the installer. So we have a mix of own compiled files (potentially including harmful libraries) and 3rd party binaries from multiple sources (nuget, sdks..) that should be checked before packaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files not in the SophosLabs dataset will get a score of 30, meaning unknown. This score will vary over time based on information available to SophosLabs. See the file lookup response in the [API documentation](https://api.labs.sophos.com/doc/lookup/files.html).

Should you submit files that get a score of 30 to static analysis, well; unfortunately, this depends on your use case.

For example, if you are using the tool to check documents uploaded to a web application from a customer, then I would use static analysis. In this case, most (if not all) of the uploaded documents will be unknown.

Alternatively, if you are using the tool to validate a custom block list for a Sophos product, using the file hash alone will indicate whether or not the file is known to SophosLabs.

I will happily revisit my answer if you update the question with more use case details.

Comment: Use case: Checking own compiled files and 3rd party files during build process. Example 1: When building .NET Windows desktop applications, check own and 3rd party files from nugets (especially nuget.org), 3rd party runtimes and SDKs before generating the installer msi file.
Example 2: When building Electron based applications, check all included 3rd party binaries before generating the installer.

So we have a mix of own compiled files (potentially including harmful libraries) and 3rd party binaries from multiple sources (nuget, sdks..) that should be checked before packaging.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. For pre-compiled libraries / binaries the cloud lookup may help. However, for the own compiled files I would definitely use the static analysis as SophosLabs are highly unlikely to have seen these files before.